# Ajax call to controller action: RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax call to controller action.

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({url: "offerings/remove_from_sale", type: "POST"})
```

controller:

```
class Manage::GroundServiceController < ApplicationController

  def remove_from_sale
    Ts::User.all.each do |user|
      unless user.ground_service == nil
        if user.ground_service.ID == params[:id]
          true
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

routes:

```
namespace :manage do
    resources :ground_service, except: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] do

      collection do

        get :edit
        get :products

        resources :events, only: [:show, :update] do 
          member do
            post :accept
          end
        end

        resources :offerings, only: [:update, :remove_from_sale]
        resources :prices, only: [:update]
      end
    end
end
```

There is an error

```
No route matches [POST] "/manage/ground_service/offerings/remove_from_sale"
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I put `remove_from_sale` action to `offerings_controller`? Please ask if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove_from_sale` is not default resource route, so you must specify it:

```
resources :offerings, only: :update do
  collection do
    post :remove_from_sale
  end
end
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Can you help with next problem? There is an error `Template is missing` manage/offerings/remove_from_sale, but I don't need view file for this action

Comment: @Gvcci it's another question and I can't help without some context.

Comment: Since you are calling it through an ajax, your method remove_from_sale probably needs a format.js line oryou can add the render :nothing => true if no template is needed

Answer (score 0):

If your url doesn't start with a slash, it will add it to the current page url.  Try putting a slash at the start of your ajax url.

Comment: It's desired in this case.

Comment: ah. fair enough then.  Personally i always use the full path with any request.

Comment: Me too. Anyway, it's not the source of the problem.